# What is the definition of "rare events"? and when it matters for significance testing of differences in a control-case study?

Tags: regression, logistic, definition, rare-events

What is the formal definition of "rare events"? and when it matters for significance testing of differences in a control-case study?

Comment: Thanks. That's very helpful. But can you also suggest a formal definition of "rare events"?

Comment: Well that definition is quite sharp: if the proportion of true cases is lower than or equal to 1/12 = 8% then we are dealing with a rare event and we might need to adjust our tools to account for that. I also agree that why 8% instead of 5% remains unclear, but I guess they use simulation results to show that 8% is the way to go...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Definition**
The abstract to "[Logistic Regression in Rare Events Data](http://gking.harvard.edu/files/gking/files/0s.pdf)" (reference 1) has no intent to define, but provides description of "rare event" data as "binary dependent variables with dozens to thousands of times fewer ones (events, such as wars, vetoes, cases of political activism, or epidemiological infections) than zeros ("nonevents"). Since this description spans a wide range (1 in 12 to 1 in 1000), I find it somewhat unsatisfying.

**2. Significance**
One of Gary King's research interests is the study of rare events. He's in the Department of Government (at Harvard) so he comes at it from a political science perspective. A selection of articles describing difficulties and solutions to working with rare events data can be found on his webpage, [here](http://gking.harvard.edu/category/research-interests/methods/rare-events).

1. King, Gary, and Langche Zeng. 2001. “Logistic Regression in Rare Events Data.” *Political Analysis* 9: 137–163. Copy at https://gking.harvard.edu/files/abs/0S-Abs.shtml